# How to render prototype with Sonata's FormMapper?

Tags: forms, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataAdmin to manage my entities as CRUD.
Currently I need to render a `prototype` FormType for a collection, but this collection is rendered with Sonata's `CollectionType` (not the native-collection from Symfony).

So my code looks like follows: (Entity 1:N Sub-Entity)

```
// EntityAdmin

public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    // ... fields

    /* Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType, rendering SubEntityAdmin */
    ->add(
        'subentity', 
         null, 
         ['label' => false, 'required' => false], 
         ['edit' => 'inline', 'inline' => 'standard']
    )

    // ...
 }
```

What I want to achieve is rendering a new prototype-Form field like in `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType` but with the stylings given by Sonata's form-mapping.

I didn't found anything in Sonata's repo, nor on the internet on how to use a prototype here (yes, instead of the append-form-field functionality via AJAX).
Is this somehow possible? I need to add new elements (custom) via Javascript (on client side) by maintaining maximum compatibility and re-usability of the FormMapper.